# My Excel files show some blue dot lines between rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

For some reason when I open a certain file in Excel, it shows some ugly dotted blue lines between rows.

I kind of eliminate them using the menu [View] -> Workbook Views and changing from Page Break Preview to Normal, but still there are some ugly gray dotted lines

What is this page break preview? And what can I do to show a normal clear page without these lines?

A screenshot with the blue lines

[image]

And without the blue lines

[image]

Comment: I imagine you can change color of cell lines, I know you can thicken them & changed them into dashes. A picture may help us understand

Comment: Page break preview shows you where a physical paper print would 'break' to the next page, AKA it shows you how much fits on a single printed page

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot so we can see what these lines are you're talking about? Without that we're only guessing what it is that you're trying to fix.

Comment: @music2myear   I added some screenshots

Comment: Also, before you change anything, ask around at the office. This may be by design by someone who made the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Page Setup` and set the page print areas to 1 by 1 pages.  If the problem still persists, you can select all cells using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Context Menu</kbd>, then <kbd>D</kbd> to **delete** (not clear) highlighted cells; this should clear non-default print-area dilineations (AFAIR).  In the page-break view, you can also click and drag the blue dotted lines and blue solid lines to visually set the page- and print-area boundries respectively (the gray areas are non-print).

Answer (score 0):

You're in "page break view", you can switch back to normal view at the bottom right corner or in the Workbook views group of view tab.

[image]

[image]